# Cannot able to render to main home page from index.html in Angular (Angular Migration)

Tags: angular, jhipster

I have recently migrated existing angular project from 10.1.3  to 14.2.6  and using jhipster version 7.9.3   for project
I have upgraded older project  package.json with latest version But when I tried to run my project
Its showing jhipster error message  which is coming from index.html file

**An error has occurred :-(
Usual error causes
You started the application from an IDE and you didn't run npm start or npm run webpack:build.
You had a network error while running npm install. If you are behind a corporate proxy, it is likely that this error was caused by your proxy. Have a look at the JHipster error logs, you will probably have the cause of the error.
You installed a Node.js version that doesn't work with JHipster: please use an LTS (long-term support) version, as it's the only version we support.**

main component html file is not being rendered from this index.html file  instead its showing jhipster logs only

I tried to google it to find root cause of this issue but cannot able to procced and build project for this new angular

Is there any library compatibility issue for new angular version or do I need to downgrade to lower version of angular and jhipster to make it work

Any suggestion and feedback will be helpful for me

Thank you

Comment: You did not say how you were running your backend and frontend. As this is an existing app, I suppose that you know how to do it. Have you tried deleting node_modules and running `npm install`, before running back and front as usual?

Comment: Yes  I updated existing package.json to new version  and then  tried deleting node modules and run npm install forcefully to generate new node modules folder but still getting issue while running

Comment: You probably have some more detailed error either in browser's console or in java backend.